# Fetch API POST to Node-js only 6 times

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was trying to use the Fetch API POST method in Vanilla JS. The endpoint was located in Node-JS code.
The POST method function run whenever ONKEYDOWN function runs on html text input. Whenever we type on keyboard, it sends data to the Node-JS Endpoint and then prints it. Each time I typed, the data was being sent but was only received only 6 times before it stopped printing the **req.body**.

Here's is my code for HTML + Vanilla JS (index.html).

```
 <div onkeydown="post()">
            First Name
            <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName">
            <br> <br>
            Middle Name
            <input type="text" name="MiddleName" id="MiddleName">
            <br> <br>
            Last Name
            <input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName">
        </div>

  <script>
            function post() {
                const formData = {
                    FirstName: document.getElementById('FirstName').value,
                    MiddleName: document.getElementById('MiddleName').value,
                    LastName: document.getElementById('LastName').value,
                }
                localStorage.setItem("FirstName", formData.FirstName)
                localStorage.setItem("MiddleName", formData.MiddleName)
                localStorage.setItem("LastName", formData.LastName)
                console.log(formData);

                fetch('/', {
                    method: 'post',
                    headers: {
                 

   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(formData)
            })
        }
    </script>
```

Here's is my Code for Node-js (index.js)

```
 const express = require('express')
 const app = express()
 app.use(express.json({ limit: '20mb'}))
 app.use(express.static('/')) //static folder
 
 
 app.listen(80, () => {
     console.log('THE PORT IS UP AND RUNNING')
 })
 
 app.get('/', (req, res) => {
     res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname })
 })
 
 let i = 0; // to display the number of outputs
 app.post('/', (req, res) => {
     console.log(req.body, i++)
     // print the data
 })
```

According to this code, I recieve the **req.body** only for 6 times which is printed in the terminal (6 times). Please help

Comment: does your console log throw any error after 6 times?

Comment: no, it does not. it just stops functioning.

Answer (score 2):

You need to send response to previous requests.
The easiest way to achieve it is to call `.end()` method of the `res` object

```
// print the data
res.end();
```

Your requests don't hit the server due to browser's concurrent requests limit which is 6 for some browsers including Google Chrome. Browser waits for pending requests to finish before sending next ones, but your server never sends response.

Comment: Thank you Mate. Have a good and prosperous day!